# Using Ant to deploy folder with Tomcat Manager

Tags: tomcat, ant

I've been trying to copy over a folder from my local machine to a network machine using the the Manager Commands with Ant build for deployment. I've created a shared folder to allow full access on the network. However, when executing the command, its deploying the application as a .war file and error return java.io.IOException: insufficient data written.

I'm using the tutorial *Executing Manager Commands with Ant* from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

Specfying the path to deploy and then *ant deploy* doesn't seem to work with directories, only war files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the folder an the networkmaschine, as for example with the ant copy task. Then create a file  on tomcat-install\conf\Catalina\localhost with the name mywebapppath.xml and the following content

```
<Context docBase="path-to-the-app" debug="0" crossContext="true" >

</Context>
```

path-to-the-app folder ist the folder containing the WEB-INF - folder

Tomcat load the content of the folder as webapp with the contextname mywebapppath.